# How to get account code to display in error message

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, mysql, asp.net

I am trying to create some validation for a form.

The user can enter in account code, name, address, etc for companies. I need to create the validation for the name text box. If they enter a name that already exists then display the message "This name already exists on account code: " then display the account code.

The problem is I don't know how to get the account code of the company.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtName" onblur="CheckIfNameExists(this.value)"></asp:TextBox>

 function CheckIfNameExists(Name) {
        PageMethods.CheckIfNameExists(Name,
                                        OnCheckIfNameExists,
                                        null
                                        );
    }

    function OnCheckIfNameExists(result){
        if(result){
            alert("This Name already exists!");
        }
        else{
        }
    }
```

Web method for checking bool:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static bool CheckIfNameExists(string Name)
    {
        try
        {
            if(Creditor.CheckIfNameCreditorExists(Company.Current.CompanyID, Name))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
               return false;
            }                    
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Right now the code just checks if the name already exists in the database. But I want to get the account code of the name in the database.

This is the code that searches the database:

```
public static bool CheckIfNameCreditorExists(int CompanyID, string Name)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    string sql = "proc_CheckIfACCreditorExists";

    string query = "SELECT c.* " +
        " FROM Creditor c " +
        " WHERE c.Company_ID = " + CompanyID + " AND c.Name LIKE '" + Name + "' ";


    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter(query, DataUtils.ConnectionStrings["TAT"]))
    {
        adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = query;
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: How about returning a json...Newtonsoft Json can serialize a Datatable into json in no time

Comment: @Hackerman I don't want to download a new framework just to get an account code

Comment: Is the account code include in your `string query` ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the return type of your method to string from bool

<strike>bool</strike> is replaced with **string** in below code snippet

```
public static string CheckIfNameCreditorExists(...
```

Now, change your return type. I am just rewriting your return lines only.

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        //Make sure to use right column name here
        return string.format("{Exist: true, AccountNo: {0}}", dt.Rows["AccNo"]); 
    }
    return return "{Exist: false, AccountNo: null}";
```

Finally, modify javascript method as below.

```
function OnCheckIfNameExists(result){
    if(result.Exist){
        alert("This Name already exists!");
        alert("Associated Account Number is: " + result.AccountNo);
    }
    else{
    }
}
```

Only possible issue is: Sometimes, returned json string will not be parsed automatically. In that case rather than directly referring result, you can parse Json to object and use its properties in javascript method.

Comment: sorry I forgot to show the web method for the jquery function `function CheckIfNameExists`. If I change the sql function from bool to string then what do I need to change in the web method?

Comment: also I get an error on the line: `return string.Format("{Exist: true, AccountCode: {0}}", dt.Rows["AccountCode"]); ` Error 158 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.DataRowCollection.this[int]' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score -1):

I would call the method using jquery.

[jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
function CheckIfNameExists(Name) {
    $.ajax("CheckIfNameCreditorExists?companyID=[value]&name=[value]").done(
    function(result) {
        if(result){
            alert("This Name already exists!");
        }
        else {
        }
    });
}
```

You can do it in POST or GET as you wish.

Comment: that code stops the alert message from showing. And I don't see how it gets the account code..

Comment: I think you can use jquery to identify the textbox and get the value : $("#txtName").val() ?

Comment: I don't need to find the name. I need to find the account number of the name. Right now my code checks to see if the name already exists. I need to get the account number of that name and display the account number in the alert

Comment: Change your method in the code behind and return a JSON object with the account number ?